# mysql multiple transaction rollback problem

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to have multiple procedure call and one transaction commit, for example:

```sql
call CreateRestaurant(?, ?, ?);
call CreateMenu(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
call CreateMenuItem(?, ?, ?, ?);
```

but I want to wrap all these call procedure in one place, is there anyway to achieve this goal?

Comment: i understand your problem, but i don't thinkl that is possible, is there really a need to splitt hem up in a stored procedure,. can you noz start the transaction hammer all inpiuts inn and when there was no error commit?

Comment: dear @nbk, iterate of createMenuItem can be different from each other, for example, sometimes we have just one createMenuItem, some time we have 12, it depends of count of inputs

Comment: it is hard to explain but do a transaction for all insert s(menu/menuitem,/restaurant with lastinsertid and so on, then you get them all in one goal, and if one4 fails do a ROLLBACK, all connector can do multi query

Comment: Formally you may claim all these statements as simgle transaction writing START TRANSACTION before, and at the end - checking some flag and executing COMMIT or ROLLBACK... But there is one problem - there exists wide list of statements types which causes impicit and immediate commit. If such statement executed, then transaction committed, and ROLLBACK won't revert to initial state. You must remember this.

Comment: So for to solve the task you'd need in a lot of nested transactions with a lot ov savepoints, and this must be synced between main procedure and slaves.

Comment: I added a question and an answer similar to this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/280695).